# How do I "duplicate" a server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, chef, chef-solo

I have a EC2 and Digital Ocean servers and I want to re-create them locally (same config files and everything). By local I mean virtual box (vagrant).

I had started out by managing them with Chef but had to go around that for a while (time crunched). My Chef recipes are no longer synced with the servers.

Any way I can reverse engineer this? I tried [blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint) but wasn't able to get it to install the apps right.

Answer (score 10):

If all else fails, there's the old fashioned way - On Ubuntu or debian,[use dpkg --get-selections to dump out a list of installed packages, and install them with dpkg --set-selections](https://askubuntu.com/a/137991/17681). The equivalent of this for red hat based distros is [yum-debug-dump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yum-debug-dump) and [yum-debug-restore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-debug-restore.1.html) (optionally with --install-latest).

Create the same users as the source system if necessary - `cat /etc/passwd` should list them out, and you can check with diff to see if the two lists are identical.

Then use rsync to duplicate your `/etc/` folder for settings, various `/home/` folders for users (and check permissions here) and other folders like `/var/www/`. Test, make sure everything's there and working, and starting up as needed, and you're done. Takes me less time than to set up a fresh server.

Sometimes, the old, simple ways are the best. If you work this out manually, simply write a script that will replicate this off your current server automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to hack this together. I tried the `dpkg --set-selections` command and seems to work.